# Filter table using distinct column values and greatest value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following data, I want to unique values for columns A but I only want the record with the largest value of column B.

```
id |  A  | B
-------------    
1  | 'w' | 1
2  | 'x' | 0
3  | 'y' | 0
4  | 'z' | 0
5  | 'w' | 2
6  | 'w' | 1
7  | 'w' | 0
```

So the expected result of such a query would be this:

```
id |  A  | B
-------------    
2  | 'x' | 0
3  | 'y' | 0
4  | 'z' | 0
5  | 'w' | 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact you need `max(B)` `group by A`, I name this as **INNER GROUPING BY**, you can achieve such this grouping by using a specific `self join`:

```
select t1.id,t1.A,t1.B 
from table_name t1
     join (select A,max(B)B
           from table_name 
           group by A)t2
     on t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B
order by t1.id
```

Result:

```
id |  A  | B
-------------    
2  | 'x' | 0
3  | 'y' | 0
4  | 'z' | 0
5  | 'w' | 2
```

[THE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e01ab/6)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**ROW_NUMBER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
    id, A, B
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/820b1/1/0)